# Using internet on remote server via SSH tunnel

Tags: squid, ssh-tunnel, rhel7

I have a RHEL server accessible via jump host only. This is how i am connecting to it

`MyMachine(Win10)--SSH-->JumpHost(winserver2012r2)--SSH-->RHEL7`

via ssh

```
ssh -J user@jumphost user@RHEL7
```

I want to download few dependencies and also want to use internet for accessing few API`s on internet. My jump host also do not have internet so i am kind of stuck here. If jump host had internet i can use sqid proxy, which i am already using for some other servers. Is there any way to use internet on my RHEL7 using squid and ssh tunneling. This is how i am using internet on other servers without jumphost.

step:1 Starting sqid server on my machine

step:2 adding these lines in /etc/environment on rhel server

```
 export http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3128

 export https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3128
```

step:3 ssh -R 3128:localhost:3128 user@rhel

**I there any way to use internet on my RHEL7 server while jumphost being in middle of my machine and RHEL7**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you want to use the method you described for other servers + jump host?

```
ssh -J user@jumphost -R 3128:localhost:3128 user@rhel
```

here is an example https://dev.to/claudiohigashi/ssh-tunneling-via-a-jump-host-2b5d